# jQuery drag & drop swap places

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement a drag & drop swap places functionality, but got stuck at the point where once dragged and dropped items need to be swapped again.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skunksts/CrwcL/)

The idea is simple: i have 9 squares on a grid and every square should be swappable with any other square so that for example

```
123<br>
456<br>
789
```

after 1 and 5 swap would become

```
523<br>
416<br>
789
```

And after this all squares would be swapable again.

I would really apreciate your help as i am very new to programming and it is still very hard to find the right answers in other code which have a lot of additional functionality...
Thank you very much!

Comment: So what is your problem?what is not working ?

Comment: After i swap for the first time, I cannot swap those squares again.

Comment: is this problem for all swap or just 1,5?

Comment: It is the problem for all squares that have been swapped 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code that calls `.draggable()` on your elements is only run at document ready. The cloned elements do not have the listeners/bindings that the originals do. `$elem.clone(true, true)` should copy those as well. See the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for `.clone()`.

Optionally, in your dropped callback you could add the bindings to the clone instead. Depending on your success with `.clone(true, true)` as some SO question indicate trouble with that.

Comment: Only being called at document ready means that the newly created clones are not being selected as they do not yet exist.